# How do I get multiple slideshows on my html document?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using the W3 Schools tutorial on how to add multiple slideshows to an HTML document:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow_multiple

This is the link. However, my question is how do I add 3 slideshows to the page?

What I have tried was to copy and paste the mySlides2 section in the DIV class and change it from mySlides2 to mySlides3. And I also added mySlides3 to anything that references mySlides2 and 1. However, for mySlides3, I end up with my images just listed vertically down and next/back controls that control mySlides2. 
This is my code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">



<html>

    <body>
    <p>Face Mask</p>
    <div class="slideshow-container">
      <div class="mySlides1">
        <img src="/sample/fm1.jpg" id="border" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <div class="mySlides1">
        <img src="/sample/fm2.jpg" id="border" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <div class="mySlides1">
        <img src="/sample/fm3.jpg" id="border" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <div class="mySlides1">
        <img src="/sample/fm4.jpg" id="border" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <div class="mySlides1">
        <img src="/sample/fm5.jpg" id="border" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <div class="mySlides1">
        <img src="/sample/fm6.jpg" id="border" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <div class="mySlides1">
        <img src="/sample/fm7.jpg" id="border" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 0)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 0)">&#10095;</a>
    </div>

    <p>Deodorant</p>
    <div class="slideshow-container">
      <div class="mySlides2">
        <img src="/sample/nd1.jpg" id="border" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <div class="mySlides2">
        <img src="/sample/nd2.jpg" id="border" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <div class="mySlides2">
        <img src="/sample/nd3.jpg" id="border" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <div class="mySlides2">
        <img src="/sample/nd4.jpg" id="border" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 1)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 1)">&#10095;</a>

      <p>Deodorant</p>
      <div class="slideshow-container">
        <div class="mySlides3">
          <img src="/sample/fd1.jpg" id="border" style="width:100%">
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides3">
          <img src="/sample/fd2.jpg" id="border" style="width:100%">
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides3">
          <img src="/sample/fd3.jpg" id="border" style="width:100%">
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides3">
          <img src="/sample/fd4.jpg" id="border" style="width:100%">
        </div>
        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 1)">&#10094;</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 1)">&#10095;</a>




    </div>

    <script>
    var slideIndex = [1,1];
    var slideId = ["mySlides1", "mySlides2", "mySlides3"]
    showSlides(1, 0);
    showSlides(1, 1);

    function plusSlides(n, no) {
      showSlides(slideIndex[no] += n, no);
    }

    function showSlides(n, no) {
      var i;
      var x = document.getElementsByClassName(slideId[no]);
      if (n > x.length) {slideIndex[no] = 1}    
      if (n < 1) {slideIndex[no] = x.length}
      for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
         x[i].style.display = "none";  
      }
      x[slideIndex[no]-1].style.display = "block";  
    }
    </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

```
    * {box-sizing: border-box}
    .mySlides1, .mySlides2, .mySlides3 
// When I add .mySlides3 here, the images do not appear at all for .mySlides3
 {display: none}
    img {vertical-align: middle;}

    /* Slideshow container */
    .slideshow-container {
      max-width: 500px;
      position: relative;
      margin: auto;
    }

    /* Next & previous buttons */
    .prev, .next {
      cursor: pointer;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0%;
      width: auto;
      padding: 50px;
      color: white;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 18px;
      transition: 0.6s ease;
      border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
      user-select: none;
    }

    /* Position the "next button" to the right */
    .next {
      right: 0;
      border-radius: 0px 0 0 0px;
    }

    /* On hover, add a grey background color */
    .prev:hover, .next:hover {
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      color: black;
    }
```

Comment: I'd suggest OOP approach for the task.

Comment: Where should I start?

Comment: Is there anything simple I could do just to have that 3rd slideshow running?

Comment: From [Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes). Also creating the most of the slider elements dynamically makes everything easier. All this is maybe a hard bite now, and will have more code, but studying the OOP well will pay back in the future.

Comment: You are missing a `</div>` after the second gallery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have tested the code and also updated it. There are only a few small 3-4 changes in your HTML file. Please do replace it with your code. There are no changes in CSS file. Just replace your HTML file code with my code and you will see 3 slideshows.

**HTML FILE CODE**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">

<html>

    <body>
    <p>Face Mask</p>
    <div class="slideshow-container">
      <div class="mySlides1">
        <img src="/sample/fm1.jpg" id="border" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <div class="mySlides1">
        <img src="/sample/fm2.jpg" id="border" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <div class="mySlides1">
        <img src="/sample/fm3.jpg" id="border" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <div class="mySlides1">
        <img src="/sample/fm4.jpg" id="border" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <div class="mySlides1">
        <img src="/sample/fm5.jpg" id="border" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <div class="mySlides1">
        <img src="/sample/fm6.jpg" id="border" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <div class="mySlides1">
        <img src="/sample/fm7.jpg" id="border" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 0)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 0)">&#10095;</a>
    </div>

    <p>Deodorant</p>
    <div class="slideshow-container">
      <div class="mySlides2">
        <img src="/sample/nd1.jpg" id="border" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <div class="mySlides2">
        <img src="/sample/nd2.jpg" id="border" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <div class="mySlides2">
        <img src="/sample/nd3.jpg" id="border" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <div class="mySlides2">
        <img src="/sample/nd4.jpg" id="border" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 1)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 1)">&#10095;</a>
    </div>

    <p>Deodorant</p>
    <div class="slideshow-container">
        <div class="mySlides3">
          <img src="/sample/fd1.jpg" id="border" style="width:100%">
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides3">
          <img src="/sample/fd2.jpg" id="border" style="width:100%">
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides3">
          <img src="/sample/fd3.jpg" id="border" style="width:100%">
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides3">
          <img src="/sample/fd4.jpg" id="border" style="width:100%">
        </div>
        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 2)">&#10094;</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 2)">&#10095;</a>
    </div>

    <script>
    var slideIndex = [1,1,1];
    var slideId = ["mySlides1", "mySlides2", "mySlides3"]
    showSlides(1, 0);
    showSlides(1, 1);
    showSlides(1, 2);

    function plusSlides(n, no) {
      showSlides(slideIndex[no] += n, no);
    }

    function showSlides(n, no) {
      var i;
      var x = document.getElementsByClassName(slideId[no]);
      if (n > x.length) {slideIndex[no] = 1}    
      if (n < 2) {slideIndex[no] = x.length}
      for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
         x[i].style.display = "none";  
      }
      x[slideIndex[no]-1].style.display = "block";  
    }
    </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: also `var slideIndex = [1,1,1];`

Comment: Ok, this worked. Thank you! So if I were to want more than 3 slideshows, I would go to the script, and add "showSlides(1,3);" and "mySlides4" to the slideId, along with another 1 to the slideIndex?

Comment: if you want to add the 4th slideshow than you nee to change this. Thw argument which you are passing during the function call.
```<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 3)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 3)">&#10095;</a>```
Also you need to make changes in your script too. 
```showSlides(1, 3);``` you need to add this line too and in if condition where its is  ```if (n < 2) {slideIndex[no] = x.length}``` you need to change it to ```if (n < 3){slideIndex[no] = x.length}``` and in ```var slideIndex = [1,1,1];``` it will be like this ```var slideIndex = [1,1,1,1];```

Comment: @JimmySlimmy And likewise, if you want to add another slideshow just change it like this way.
I hope you got to know now that what changes are required if you want to add another slideshow.

Comment: @JimmySlimmy so it worked right. Please accept the answer so others get to know that question is closed.

Comment: got it, thank you very much. sorry, i was late to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a few more adjustments to the code. Your third slideshow should look like this:

```
<div class="w3-content w3-display-container">
    <img class="mySlides3" src="project2/test/block1img.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img class="mySlides3" src="project2/test/block3img.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img class="mySlides3" src="project2/test/block2img.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1, 2)">&#10094;</button>
    <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs(1, 2)">&#10095;</button>
  </div>
```

Then below, adjust like this:

```
var slideIndex = [2,1,1];
var slideId = ["mySlides1", "mySlides2", "mySlides3"]
showDivs(1, 0);
showDivs(1, 1);
showDivs(1, 2);
```

Basically, in the slideshow container for plusDivs(a, b), a refers to whether the button increments or decrements the index, while b indicates which slideshow is being changed.

In showDivs(a,b), a refers to which image is shown, while b refers to which slideshow.
var slideIndex shows which image should be shown for each slideshow.

Answer (score 0):

### Multiple slide shows On a single page

> Add some library file or CDN for this
>   CSS CDN

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

> JS CDN or script

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>        
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<style>
#slider .container-fluid{
    padding: 0 15px;
}
#slider .slider-inner{
    padding: 0;
}
.slider-inner .item img{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.slider-inner h1{
    color: purple;
}
</style>
```

### HTML for slide show

> Slide Show 1

```
  <section id="slider">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="slider-inner col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                    <h1>FIRST</h1>
                    <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="img1.jpg" alt="sliderimg1">                           
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="img2.png" alt="sliderimg2">
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="img3.png" alt="sliderimg3">
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="img4.png" alt="sliderimg3">
                        </div>
                    </div>                                       
                </div>

                <div class="slider-inner col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                    <h1>SECOND</h1>
                    <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="img1.png" alt="sliderimg1">                           
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="img2.png" alt="sliderimg2">
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="img3.png" alt="sliderimg3">
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="img4.jpg" alt="sliderimg3">
                        </div>
                    </div>                                       
                </div>

                <div class="slider-inner col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                    <h1>Third</h1>
                    <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="img1.jpg" alt="sliderimg1">                           
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="img2.png" alt="sliderimg2">
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="img3.png" alt="sliderimg3">
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="img4.png" alt="sliderimg3">
                        </div>
                    </div>                                       
                </div>
                <div class="slider-inner col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                    <h1>FOURTH</h1>
                    <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="img1.png" alt="sliderimg1">                           
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="img2png" alt="sliderimg2">
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="img3.png" alt="sliderimg3">
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="img4.jpg" alt="sliderimg3">
                        </div>
                    </div>                                       
                </div>
            </div>
   </section>
```

### Java script for slide show

```
<script>
$(function () {
    var count = 0;
    $('.owl-carousel').each(function () {
        $(this).attr('id', 'owl-demo' + count);
        $('#owl-demo' + count).owlCarousel({
            navigation: true,
            slideSpeed: 300,
            pagination: true,
            singleItem: true,
            autoPlay: 2000,
            autoHeight: true
        });
        count++;
    });
});
</script>
```